# Php splash page generator

Tags: php, generator, splash-screen

I am trying to create a splash page generator and I have a small problem.

```
$accountid = $_POST['accountid'];
```

(I also tried with $_GET and $_REQUEST and the form page is done and the name is correct)

```
$reflink = "< a href="http://www.site.com/?ref=$accountid">today< / a>";

echo "Join " . $reflink . "line breaks here;
```

The problem is that the slashes // are used for comments too and the link is not working, when removing the http:// it searches in the server files like site.com/files/site.com/?r=

I also tried with www., not working.

Any help is appreciated.

I have put some spaces inside the code, otherwise it wouldn't show properly.

Comment: Please use markdown code formatting in future: http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/ - also your comment is very confusing.. I can't understand what you're trying to acheive / whats going wrong?

Comment: simple parse error in your $reflink definition.
`$reflink="<a href='http://www.site.com/?ref=".$countid."'>today</a>";`

Comment: You need to put you code in here properly using the 4-space code system on thid board, or we can't really help you...

Comment: To solve your issue, instead of just clicking on the links to see if they work, view the generated HTML source.  If you are already doing that, show us the different kinds of generated results you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand your question, you need to escape the quotes:

```
$reflink = "< a href=\"http://www.site.com/?ref=$accountid\">today< / a>";
```

or:

```
$reflink = "< a href='http://www.site.com/?ref=$accountid'>today< / a>";
```

And if `$accountid` is an integer, I would also use:

```
$accountid = (int) $_POST['accountid'];
```

(I would clean it up anyway, but it seems it´s an integer...)

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your quote marks:

```
$reflink = "< a href=\"http://www.site.com/?ref=$accountid\">today< / a>";
```